# Limit ICMP Per Source IP with IPTables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, router

I have mistakenly thought that the limit module is per source ip, but it appears to be based on all requests:

```
  577 36987 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 limit: avg 3/sec burst 5 
   46  3478 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `INET-PING-DROP:' 
   46  3478 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
    ...
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 limit: avg 3/sec burst 5 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `WEB-PING-DROP:' 
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8
```

How can I rate limit icmp with iptables / netfilter based on the source IP address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were still wondering for a hint:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name icmp --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit 3/second --hashlimit-burst 5 -j ACCEPT
```

Assuming the last rule in INPUT is drop or the default policy is DROP. Each ip is limited to 3 pings a second (burst of 5). Not all incoming IPs total, as you found with -m limit.

Comment: Now this accept is _really_ "meta"!